# Not able to add external library using git submodules in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, git-submodules

I am trying to add `jwt-cpp` library by [Thalhammer](https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp) in my project using `CMake`.

My project structure is as follows

```
build
External
---- jwt
.gitignore
.gitmodules
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

I used command `git submodule add https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp.git External/jwt` to add the mentioned git submodule to my project. and the contents of the `.gitmodules` file is

```
[submodule "External/jwt"]
    path = External/jwt
    url = https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp.git
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.2)
set(This Trial)
project(${This} C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

set(Sources main.cpp)
add_executable(${This} ${Sources})

add_subdirectory(External/jwt)

if(NOT TARGET jwt-cpp)
  find_package(jwt-cpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()

target_include_directories(${This} INTERFACE External/jwt/include)
target_link_libraries(${This} INTERFACE jwt-cpp::jwt-cpp)
```

and my `main.cpp` is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jwt-cpp/jwt.h>

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I am facing is that everything configures builds properly if is don't include `#include <jwt-cpp/jwt.h>` in my `main.cpp` file but throws and error if I do that. The error looks like as follows:

```
fatal error: 'jwt-cpp/jwt.h' file not found
#include <jwt-cpp/jwt.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Trial.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Trial.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am not able to figure out what should I correct/edit.

Comment: Try adding add_subdirectory before add_executable.

Answer (score 0):

The `INTERFACE` property adds folders for dependent targets. You need to use the `PUBLIC` property so that folders are added to the target to be builded.